# sql syntax is not working with group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am writing sql and I am stuck in the following line

```
    select employeeid, (case paidL when'1' 
                               Then
                               1
                                   when '0'
                               Then
                               0
                               end) as 'paidLeave' from Lea order by employeeid group by 'paidLeave'
```

The above line if giving me error related to 'paidLeave'

Any help to improve the syntax to remove the error will be appreciated

Comment: Your `case` syntax is wrong.  Hint:  a `case` expression starts with `case`, not `when`.

Comment: Even when you fix the case expression the way you have coded this it will try to group by the string literal 'paidLeave'

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx for syntax

Comment: @GordonLinoff I corrected the code but what u pointed out is my solving me problem

Comment: You fixed the case expression, now drop the pointless quotes around your alias in the column name and the group by.

Comment: must be  `group by paidL`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your case syntax is obviously wrong.  But you have another error:  *Never* use single quotes for column aliases.  This is an example of an error waiting to happen.

It is best to use column and table names that do not need to be escaped.  If they do, use square braces or double quotes.

The query you want should look like this:

```
select employeeid, 
       (case when paidL = '1' then 1
             when paidl = '0 then 0
        end) as paidLeave
from Lea
order by employeeid;
```

I have no idea what `group by 'paidleave'` is supposed to do.  It is syntactically wrong on two fronts.  If you want the sum, then the query would be something like:

```
select employeeid, 
       sum(case when paidL = '1' then 1
                when paidl = '0 then 0
           end) as paidLeave
from Lea
group by employeeid;
```

I think you need to study up on basic SQL syntax.  There are many resources on the web and in books.

Comment: Why the hell did this answer got 3 upvotes when our answer is pretty much the same and I answered first?

Comment: @sagi Your answer was less complete 5 minutes ago, Gordon got more info there quicker...it's that simple. Personally I'm not in the habit of spoon feeding the OP, just giving them enough to work it out themselves.

Comment: @Lankymart My answer was more completed 5 minutes ego, I edited the question about 4 times, so it just appears as all the edits done at the same time!

Answer (score 1):

Your case syntax is all wrong, use this :

```
 select employeeid, (case when paidL  = '1' 
                          Then 1
                          when paidL = '0'
                          Then  0
                    end) as paidLeave 
 from Lea   
 order by employeeid
```

Also, order by comes after group by!

Another thing, quote marks are used for strings, not column names. Maybe you meant ` but you don't have to do this because this is not a reserved word.

This whole query seems wrong, the group by doesn't make any sense if you have more then one employee, maybe you meant to group by emplooyeid and order by paidleave?

Maybe you meant to group by employee id and select the maximm paidLeave? in this case:

```
 select employeeid, max((case when paidL  = '1' 
                          Then 1
                          when paidL = '0'
                          Then  0
                    end)) as paidLeave 
 from Lea   
 group by employeeid 
 order by employeeid
```

Comment: I did, and I answered your question @Alex

Answer (score 0):

The [`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) syntax is incorrect, it should follow the form;

```
CASE
  WHEN <condition> THEN <result>
  ... (multiples of WHEN ... THEN ...)
  ELSE <result>
END [Alias]
```

So something like;

```
CASE
  WHEN [paidL] = '1' THEN 1
  WHEN [paidL] = '0' THEN 0
END [paidLeave]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to better help you should provide the error. However, at first sight I would say your error is, you do not have included the `employeeid` column as part of the `GROUP BY`. Also I won't use a `CASE` statement for something you can resolve with casting. You could either `CAST` the `paidL` column to either `INT` or to `BIT` (just if values are only 0/1).

```
CAST([paidL] AS INT) paidL
CAST([paidL] AS BIT) paidL
```